# How do I deploy django webapp on apache2 server without having the domain name

Tags: python, django, deployment, apache2

here is my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/firstweb.wsgi

ServerName ec2-66-***-52-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Alias /static /var/www/firstweb/static/

<Directory /var/www/firstweb/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

normally in online tutorials they want me to put the ServerName as the webdomain I brought, but I want my django app to be hosted on the servers localhost itself. Say when I put the type the ip address of the server, or ec2 address as I did above on the browser, my django app should show up.

With my current configuration I'm getting a 403 error, saying I don't have permission to access /

normally when I deploy django using the default python server, I just do,

```
> python manage.py runserver ec2-66-***-52-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80
```

and then when I open ec2-66-***-52-61.compute-1.amazonaws.com on my browser, my app shows up. Basically I want to replicate this using apache2

I don't have a domain address yet, I just want to type the public ip/ the ec2 address, on my computer and my django app should show up on it. What do?

Comment: can you post your settings.py?  Main things are if you're running in development mode and if not, if you've configured the allowed_hosts for the public address

Comment: should I post a gist of settings.py?

Comment: And I'm sorry I didn't get in a reply due to leaving for work; please note that you should now make sure you change the secret key to prevent folks from being naughty.

Comment: its a temporary ec2 instance, so no worries

Comment: I put the above conf file in the default conf file and now its giving me the 403 error, apparently its to do with file permissions now.. I'm new to linux, so figuring out what's what.

Comment: Where *exactly* are you putting that configuration? And what distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: I made it work now, just needed to change the default configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ubuntu, in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ I dont know what happened, but things are working now.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in this situation myself and I always give the site a 'dummy' name which I then enter into the hosts file on the machine I'm am browsing from.

.conf (on the server)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.dev
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts (on the machine you are browsing the site from)

```
mysite.dev    <IP address of the server>
```

This hosts entry will work on a windows machine, but on linux or mac you need to swap the order:

```
<IP address of server>    mysite.dev
```

On a windows machine you will find the hosts file at %SYSTEM32%\etc\drivers\hosts (the file has no extension in windows, linux or mac)

On linux or mac it is located at /etc/hosts and you will need root or sudo access to edit it

Comment: can I then access the url from another computer? I believe the hosts file will redirect only on the host computer?

Comment: when I did that, by redirecting the mysite.dev to the public ip of my ec2 instance. and the link in browser, its showing the default index.html of apache2 and not my django app. here is the address http://54.205.52.61/ dont do anything naughty pls.

Comment: First, you can access the URL from any computer, but you'll need to add the hosts entry on whatever computer you're trying to browse from.
The fact that you're getting the default index.html from apache2 means that the URL part is working correctly. It now looks like you are having problems with the conf file so you should create another question about that as it is a separate issue. Leave a link to the new question here and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: No I dont want to change the hosts file on every computer that accesses the url. I want my django app to be deployed on the localhost of my server, so that if I type the public ip of my server on any browser my app should show up.

Comment: In that case you'll need to change apache's default conf to point to your django app. If your site is on an Ubuntu or Debian box this would mean editing /etc/sites-available/default